# PHP SQL ON DUPLICATE KEY having no affect

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I only want to insert if there are no entries where "name" and "email" exist together.

So it's ok if "name" exists with a different e-mail or vica versa.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO 
             list (name,email) 
             VALUES ('$name','$email') 
             ON DUPLICATE KEY 
             UPDATE name='$name',email='$email'");
```

I've made both name & email primary keys but the ON DUPLICATE statement is having no effect.

Comment: could you show the table definition?

Comment: execute query `show create table \`list\`;`

Comment: CREATE TABLE `list` (
 `mail_key` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `name` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`mail_key`,`name`,`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=20 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If name and email is your combined unique key, it makes no sense to trigger the update statement (overwriting with the exact same values) if a dataset already exists. In such a case I would really only INSERT and then check if the database responds with a key constraint violation. This is the expected error that is then ignored. Anything else is still an error.

I wouldn't silence this with this NO-OP update.

Comment: Actually `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` with same values won't modify anything. So it's practically the same, but you don't need to handle errors.

Comment: I hear what your saying but have no idea how to write that statement

Comment: NOT adding "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE".

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, is my combined unique key statement right...ALTER TABLE `list`
  DROP PRIMARY KEY,
   ADD PRIMARY KEY(
     `list_key`,
     `name`,
     `email`);

Comment: @user1209203: I have given a solution for you issue in my answer. You don't need to drop existing primary key, you need to create **another** unique key

Comment: Thanks zerkms also but Sven is right about leaving out the DUPLICATE statement it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a composite unique key to have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` worked:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name_email ON list (name, email);
```

that is why it called `ON DUPLICATE **KEY** UPDATE`

Comment: And unique keys don't work of any of its columns allow NULL values.